# Multi-threading: How to run different functions in different threads?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

How can you run two or three different functions in different threads in python?

For instance, if I created some sample functions as below.

```
def method1(x,y):
     calc = x*y
     print(calc)

def method2(x,y):
     calc = x+y
     print(calc)

def method3(x,y):
     calc = x-y
     print(calc)
```

How would I be able to run all three functions at the same time in different threads?

Comment: Pretty much exactly the same way you would run any one of them in a separate thread — just do in 2 or 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example using `ThreadPoolExecutor` (available in python3)

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def method1(x,y):
     calc = x*y
     print(calc)

def method2(x,y):
     calc = x+y
     print(calc)

def method3(x,y):
     calc = x-y
     print(calc)

pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
x = 5
y = 6
pool.submit(method1, x, y)
pool.submit(method2, x, y)
pool.submit(method3, x, y)
```